# Annotate django query if filtered row exists in second table

Tags: django, postgresql

I have two tables (similar to the ones below):

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    piece = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class User_Piece (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    piece = models.ForeignKey(Piece)
```

I want to do a query that returns all items in `Piece`, but annotates each row with whether or not the logged in user owns that piece (so there exists a row in `User_Piece` where user is the logged in user).

I tried:

```
pieces = Piece.objects.annotate(owned=Count('user_piece__id'))
```

But it puts a count > 0 for any piece that is owned by *any* user. I'm not sure where/how I put in the condition that the user_piece must have the specified user I want. If I filter on `user__piece__user=user`, then I don't get all the rows from Piece, only those that are owned.

Answer (score 23):

You could use `Exist` subquery wrapper:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

subquery = User_Piece.objects.filter(user=user, piece=OuterRef('pk'))
Piece.objects.annotate(owned=Exists(subquery))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of Django, you can do:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

pieces = Piece.objects.annotate(
   owned=Exists(UserPiece.objects.filter(piece=OuterRef('id'), user=request.user))
)

for piece in pieces:
    print(piece.owned) # prints True or False
```

Of course, you can replace the name `owned` with any name you want.

Answer (score 0):

Easy approach, be careful with performance:

```
pk_pices = ( User_Piece
            .objects
            .filter(user=user)
            .distinct()
            .values_list( 'id', flat=True)
           )
pieces = pieces.objects.filter( id__in = pk_pieces )
```

Also, notice that you have a [n:m relation ship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), you can rewrite models as:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    piece = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='User_Piece',  #<- HERE!
                                   related_name='Pieces')       #<- HERE!
```

And get user pieces as:

```
pieces = currentLoggedUser.pieces.all()
```

Comment: I want all of the pieces, not just those owned by the user. But I want to know for each piece if it *is* owned by the user.

For example, assume there are four pieces and User A owns pieces 2 and 4. 

I want it to return something like: 
`Id, Cost, Piece, Owned
1, 15, "piece 1", 0
2, 10, "piece 2", 1
3, 20, "piece 3", 0
4, 15, "piece 4", 1`

Comment: I think I've determined that this is just impossible and that I'm better of with two queries. First query to get all items from Pieces. Second query to make a list of the piece id's from user_piece that match the specific user. Then, when I'm going through all the items, I can check it the id appears in the user_piece list and if so - do something special.

Comment: @akajb, yes, this is the right approach. For better performance preload all second query in a dictionary: ` dict_2q = dict( User_Piece.objects....values_list( 'id','count' ) )`